# iptables drop host domain not in list

Tags: linux, debian, iptables

I would like to block any traffic that does not come for the websites hosted on my VPC.

My Server's IP address is 1.2.3.4 which hosts 3 websites.

Following requests should be allowed:

- http:// example1.com or https:// www.example1.com
- http:// example2.com/ or https:// www.example2.com
- http:// example3.com/ or https:// www.example3.com

Following requests should be blocked (including server's IP address):

- http: //1.2.3.4/ or https:// 1.2.3.4/
- http:// anyotherdomain.com/ or https:// anyotherdomain.com/

List of allowed Host names could be read from a text file which I could update as and when required.

Is this feasible? If yes, what are the pros and cons. If not, thank you for the information.

Cheers

Comment: You cannot filter by DNS names. You can filter only by IP addresses.

Comment: TStackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for network configuration help, tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  Probably more appropriate at http://superuser.com . ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in iptables as you would like to.
What you have aren't 3 real different hosts, but 3 virtual hosts: the main difference, as you already know, is that they share the same IP address.

As they share the same IP, kernel's netfilter just can't distinguish different requests from its layer: it's your web server application itself that "routes" the different requests to its proper website by looking at the *"Host:"* header inside the incoming HTTP packet and by determining which virtualhost should reply to it.

A good compromise (denying instead of dropping) for what you want to do would be to setup a configuration in your web server to make it catch and deny any connection that doesn't belong to your virtual hosts. Also there's no need to make a different list in this way, as your web server could dinamically determine if the requested host exists or not.

Here's an example, assuming you're running Apache, adding the **catchall** sentence to the top will make your server respond with a 403 message to any connection that won't be overridden by your examples.com websites:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName catchall
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example1
    <Directory /var/www/example1>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

...

VirtualHost for example2.com (allowing all as above)

VirtualHost for example3.com (allowing all as above)
```

That's not the same as dropping right from the kernel of course, but it stops any further interation with your server aswell.

Comment: I am currently blocking using mod_security and was wondering if I could block it even earlier. I understand, this is not possible. Thanks Defrag and ceving.

Comment: You could do it, that's not impossibile, it just requires some programming skills and time to spend (as I'm not aware of a program like that as far as I know) and that maybe doesn't worth the fight... you could try to make a middleware daemon process to act as a firewall and catch the packets just **after** netfilter, on port 80. Then it must drop them or pass them to Apache based upon it's "Host:" value in the header.

Comment: Anyway, that would not make too much sense... you can simply do quite the same using mod_security. If you need these security features and don't want Apache to handle that, best way still remains to use **different IPs for different hosts** and then work efficiently on IP layer.

Comment: Cheers Defrag. I will stick to mod_security for now.